# Set theory - set inclusions and symmetric differences

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $E,F,E_k,F_k$ be arbitrary sets. I am trying to show the following relations:

$$(i) \space (E_k-F_k) \Delta (E-F) \subset (E_K \Delta E) \cup (F_k \Delta F),$$ $$(ii) \space (E_k \cup F_k) \Delta (E \cup F) \subset (E_K \Delta E) \cup (F_k \Delta F),$$$$(iii) \space (E_k \cap F_k) \Delta (E \cap F) \subset (E_K \Delta E) \cup (F_k \Delta F)$$

I've tried to use the definitions with respect to the set operations used but I got stuck. For example, in $(i)$, if $x \in (E_k-F_k) \Delta (E-F)$, then $x \in (E_k-F_k)-(E-F)$ or $x \in (E-F)-(E_k-F_k)$. From there I've tried to conclude that $x \in (E_K \Delta E) \cup (F_k \Delta F)$ but I couldn't. I would appreciate if someone could suggest me ways to prove one of the three relations so I can follow from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $x\in A\triangle B$ if and only if it is in exactly one of these sets. If $x\in(E_k-F_k)\triangle(E-F)$ then $x$ is in exactly one of these sets, if it is in $E_k-F_k$ then either $x\in E\cap F$ or $x\notin E$, in the former it follows in that $x\in F_k\triangle F$ and in the latter $x\in E_k\triangle E$.

Similar analysis can be used on the other two inclusions.